# How to tell Mathematica to treat all numbers (including those in decimal form) as arbitrary precision numbers

Tags: machine-precision, arbitrary-precision

I have code that is essentially numerical.  It uses functions like `NDSolve` and `NIntegrate`.  But in most interesting cases, the numerics are quite delicate and requires increasing the `WorkingPrecision` and `PrecisionGoal`.

Most of the numbers appearing in the equations in `NIntegrate` and `NDSolve` are given in decimal form: like `eps = 0.0001` and `xMax = 20.5`.  *Mathematica* treats these as `MachinePrecision` numbers.  This causes error messages by `NDSolve` and `NIntegrate` when `WorkingPrecision` is increased:

> "The precision of the equations/integrand is less than the working precision"

So if I want these numerical functions to accommodate any value for `WorkingPrecision`, it seems I have to express these numbers like `eps = 1/10000` and `xMax = 205/10` or `` eps=0.0001`100000000000 `` and `` xMax = 20.5`10000000000 ``.  These options make for unreadable code.

For the sake of readable code, how do I tell Mathematica that **all** numbers are to be treated as arbitrary precision numbers?

Comment: Have you seen [Arbitrary‐Precision Numbers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html), [Arbitrary‐Precision Calculations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionCalculations.html), [How to | Control the Precision and Accuracy of Numerical Results](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ControlThePrecisionAndAccuracyOfNumericalResults.html)?

Answer (score 2):

An example:

```
f = 2.45 x^2 - 0.76 x - 12/5;
NSolve[f, x, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

> NSolve::precw: "The precision of the argument function ({-(12/5)-0.76\ x+2.45\ x^2}) is less than WorkingPrecision (30). "

```
NSolve[Rationalize[f, 0], x, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
(* {{x -> -0.846720538186604156791220026903}, 
    {x -> 1.15692461981925721801570982282}}*)
```

or

```
NSolve[SetPrecision[f, 30], x, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
(* {{x -> -0.84672053818660412931604119279},
    {x ->  1.15692461981925717167460037451}} *)
```